# Errors say that unexpected syntax error is that </script> is unexpected, and multiple HTML onclick events aren't defined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

So I'm doing my assignment, due tomorrow (this is the extension aspect). 
Two errors come up when I click buttons:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: list is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

This happens with all of the functions I have.
2nd error is this:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

And apparently this error is this `</script>` tag.

I've tried changing code, functions and more but nothing seems to change.

```
  <body>
        <div id="navbar">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <a href="/form.html">Tasks</a>
            <a href="/dbform.html">DB Tasks</a>
            <ul class-"nav navbar-nav">
              <li>
                <a href="/">Home Page</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/welcome">Welcome!</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="list">List of tasks!</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <h1>To Do List</h1>
        <h2>List your tasks</h2>
        <button onclick="list()">List all tasks</button>
        <h2>Add a task</h2>
        <p>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Task ID" id="taskId">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Task Description" id="taskDesc">

          <input type="button" value="Add task" onclick="addTask()">
        </p>
        <h2>Delete a task</h2>
        <p>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Task ID" id="taskId2">
          <input type="button" value="Delete task" onclick="deleteTask()">
        </p>
        <h2>Show your tasks in a table</h2>
        <p>
          <button onclick="makeTable()">Table To Do List</button>
          <table id="makeTable" border="1">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th align="left">ID</th>
                <th align="left">Description</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tableBody">

            </tbody>
          </table>

        </p>
        <p id="msg">  </p>
        <script>
        /*
        This links the list from server.js to form.html.The fetch is used to fetch the localhost:3000/list
        link so all tasks can be displayed.
        */
        async function list() {
          let response =  await fetch('/tasks', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
          });

          let jsonPayload = await response.json();

          var data = document.getElementById("msg");
          data.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(jsonPayload);
        }
        /*
        This fetch(url) utilises the /add url so the textboxes essentially do the same thing
        as the /add?id=<number>&desc=<string>, so when the add task button is clicked, a task is added.
        */
        function addTask() {

          var url = "/tasks";

          //Puts all values inside the object.
          var data = {
            "id": taskId,
            "desc": taskDesc,
          }

          //This fetch requests take the url /tasks and fetches it using the POST method, which creates the tasks.
          fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            //The url tasks which is fetched with POST method uses req.bodyParser to get the data, so the data object - containing the information about the task, has been converted to JSON.
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
          })
        /*
        This utilises the /delete url in the localhost website. It is like the add task button, except instead of
        doing the same thing as /add it does /delete. The fetch url "fetches" the /delete url.
        */
        function deleteTask() {
          //the variable "taskId", is the number submitted in the text box to delete the selected task.
          var taskId = document.getElementById("taskId2").value;

          //the url that is fetched with the taskId variable which deletes the function.
          var url = "/tasks/"+taskId;

          //fetches /tasks with the DELETE method
          fetch(url, {
            method: "DELETE",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
          });

          //display(); calls the display function to list the tasks again without the deleted tasks
          display();
        }

        async function makeTable() {
          let response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/list");
          let data = await response.json();
          let tableBody = document.getElementById("tableBody");

          for (var i = data.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
            let row = tableBody.insertRow(0);
            let col1 = row.insertCell(0);
            let col2 = row.insertCell(1);
            col1.innerHTML = data[i].id;
            col2.innerHTML = data[i].desc;
          }
        }
        </script>
      </body>
      </html>
```

And the error is:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: list is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Answer (score 0):

Had a look at the whole thing...
Not very formatted as I did it very quickly but this seemed to remove some of the errors:

```
<html>
<body>
        <div id="navbar">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <a href="/form.html">Tasks</a>
            <a href="/dbform.html">DB Tasks</a>
            <ul class-"nav navbar-nav">
              <li>
                <a href="/">Home Page</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/welcome">Welcome!</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="list">List of tasks!</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <h1>To Do List</h1>
        <h2>List your tasks</h2>
        <button onclick="list()">List all tasks</button>
        <h2>Add a task</h2>
        <p>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Task ID" id="taskId">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Task Description" id="taskDesc">

          <input type="button" value="Add task" onclick="addTask()">
        </p>
        <h2>Delete a task</h2>
        <p>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Task ID" id="taskId2">
          <input type="button" value="Delete task" onclick="deleteTask()">
        </p>
        <h2>Show your tasks in a table</h2>
        <p>
          <button onclick="makeTable()">Table To Do List</button>
          <table id="makeTable" border="1">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th align="left">ID</th>
                <th align="left">Description</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tableBody">

            </tbody>
          </table>

        </p>
        <p id="msg">  </p>

        <script>
        /*
        This links the list from server.js to form.html.The fetch is used to fetch the localhost:3000/list
        link so all tasks can be displayed.
        */
        async function list() {
          let response =  await fetch('/tasks', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
          });

          let jsonPayload = await response.json();

          var data = document.getElementById("msg");
          data.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(jsonPayload);
        }
        /*
        This fetch(url) utilises the /add url so the textboxes essentially do the same thing
        as the /add?id=<number>&desc=<string>, so when the add task button is clicked, a task is added.
        */
        function addTask() {

          var url = "/tasks";

          //Puts all values inside the object.
          var data = {
            "id": taskId,
            "desc": taskDesc,
          }

          //This fetch requests take the url /tasks and fetches it using the POST method, which creates the tasks.
          fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            //The url tasks which is fetched with POST method uses req.bodyParser to get the data, so the data object - containing the information about the task, has been converted to JSON.
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
          })
        /*
        This utilises the /delete url in the localhost website. It is like the add task button, except instead of
        doing the same thing as /add it does /delete. The fetch url "fetches" the /delete url.
        */
        function deleteTask() {
          //the variable "taskId", is the number submitted in the text box to delete the selected task.
          var taskId = document.getElementById("taskId2").value;

          //the url that is fetched with the taskId variable which deletes the function.
          var url = "/tasks/"+taskId;

          //fetches /tasks with the DELETE method
          fetch(url, {
            method: "DELETE",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
          });

          //display(); calls the display function to list the tasks again without the deleted tasks
          display();
        }

        async function makeTable() {
          let response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/list");
          let data = await response.json();
          let tableBody = document.getElementById("tableBody");

          for (var i = data.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
            let row = tableBody.insertRow(0);
            let col1 = row.insertCell(0);
            let col2 = row.insertCell(1);
            col1.innerHTML = data[i].id;
            col2.innerHTML = data[i].desc;
          }
        }
        }
      </script>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Sorry for the mess... tell me if this works or not I tried it in a basic HTML viewer so I don't know if it'll work :)

Comment: @SB Just added all of the HTML. We are using apis, methods such as POST, GET and DELETE.

Comment: @SB Thanks! That first function does indeed work now, however I need everything else to work as well. Would you mind helping me with that?

Comment: I believe that some of the function brackets ({}) are missing as I added one to the end of the code in which stopped throwing the unexpected end of input error... so I think what I have done have made the whole code inside of the first function as I just added the other bracket (which evidently stops the rest from working). If you're still with me (hard to explain XD) then maybe just remove the last bracket and try to find where it belongs in the rest of the code (look carefully) as it might not belong at the end of the program ()

Comment: @SB If you are talking about curly brackets {} I'm fairly sure one is missing here:
function addTask() {

                var url = "/tasks";
                var data = {
                  "id": taskId,
                  "desc": taskDesc,
                }
                fetch(url, {
                  method: "POST",
                  body: JSON.stringify(data),
                  headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                  }
                });
As you can see there are 4 openers but 3 closers. I don't know where it should go though.

Comment: Yep, the curly ones! That is where it needs to go! I believe it is at the end as it closes the function. If not, try moving it around until you find it :)

Comment: @SB I found where it is meant to go! Only problem is, whenever I press the button to add the task, it doesn't get added. Any fix?

Comment: I reckon to keep playing around with the brackets and count each for every individual function (probably write it down for reference) and see if any other brackets are interfering... If not, I'll take a look a bit later :)